# what is the distribution of the log of a normal distribution?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, logarithm

if you exponentiate a normal distribution,

```
Y=exp{X}
```

where X is a normally distributed random variable (RV), then Y is log-normally distributed.

What is the distribution if you take the logarithm, instead, of a normal distribution?  In other words, if

```
Y=ln(X)
```

what is the distribution of Y?  Is there a closed-form expression, or even an empirical approximation, to that RV?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected value and variance of log(a)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/expected-value-and-variance-of-loga)

Comment: I see the math problem, but let's assume I'm doing it numerically (which is why a closed-form would be handy, even a polynomial approximation).  For example, a satellite may orbit the earth at 100 miles with a standard deviation of 1 mile...the odds of it being negative are now infinitesimal.  I could always check first to insure that P(X<0)<.0001 or whatever).

Comment: In that case the logarithm is extremely well approximated by a linear function, so the distribution is *still* normal.

Comment: Can you expand on that?  For example, if the mean were 100 miles and the stdev were 30 miles, three-sigma lower would be 10.  We could still truncate negative numbers and be "at least 99.7% right".  I strongly suspect that logarithm would not be well approximated by a normal.

Comment: I think you should consider the domain of $\log$ function. Is something wrong with me?! Acording what I understood, you want to find the distribution of $\log X$ when $X$ is normal?!!

Comment: You want to find the distribution of $\log X$ when $X$ has the normal distribution?!! The domain of the $\log$ function is $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: If $x$ is normally distributed, then the domain of $x$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$, while $\log()$ only accept values in $(0,+\infty)$. So you can't define $y=\log(x)$

Comment: Surfsnake, you are correct--but you have simply found that intermediate regime where it makes no sense to take the log, because the chance of $X$ being negative is appreciable. Because you are asking for a mathematical impossibility (as amply pointed out by the last several comments), we are struggling to make *some* practical sense of your question. In the case you posited earlier, the mean is 100 and the SD 1. The Normal approximation to $\log X$ in that case is *beautiful.*

Comment: agreed...N(100,000, 1) is going to look just like a normal curve.  I'm trying to find a way to re-pose the question where the distribution gives it sense.  Sort of like how $$exp{\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ over [-1,1] "traps" all of function between -1 and +1.